# Azure App Insights alert triggers but failure not found in logs?

Tags: azure, alert, azure-application-insights

I'm new to Application Insights Alerts and think I may have misconfigured something. I need to be alerted when an Azure Function fails to execute.

**Setup App Insights Alert**

- Trigger alert when count of failures > 1 within a 60min period
  [image]

**Alert triggered 3x in the past week**
[image]

**No failure conditions have existed on this Function since 12/2/2020**
[image]

How do I correlate an App Insights alert with its corresponding log file?

Seems like this should be a "one-click thing" but I must be missing it somewhere.

**EDIT 1:** Here is the `exceptions` table. Same findings; no fails since 12/2.

[image]

**EDIT 2:** Here is the `dependencies` table. Nothing found in last 30d.

[image]

**EDIT 3:** Per the recommendation on another post, I changed the alert from the out-of-the-box `Metric` to a `Custom log search`.

- I left the original alert (that failed for no reason) in place alongside the new one.
- The original one just failed again for no reason

**Details:**

- Alert emails say:

  - Start 2021-01-06 8:22 UTC
  - End 2021-01-06 11:22 UTC
- Function Monitor shows Function ran SUCCESSFULLY at:

  - 2021-01-06 08:13:21.368 UTC
  - 2021-01-06 08:13:21.372 UTC
- Detailed logs show the function ran successfully

[image]

At this point, I'm going to say the `Metric` version of alerts should be discarded. What ever its logic is based on has created false positives for me a number of times now.

**Stick to the `custom log search`**

[image]

Comment: can you please also check the `exceptions` table and `dependencies` table in azure portal -> application insights -> logs, to see if any errors there?

Comment: @IvanYang, please see Edit1&2 in OP. Nothing found in those tables.

Answer (score 1):

The alert is triggered when at least 2 (because that is what the treshold of > 1 means) failures occur in a timespan of 1 hour. All three alerts of last week (2nd screenshot) where triggered on a different day.

Are you sure you don't need to set the threshold to Greater than 0 so that each failure triggers the alert?

Comment: Good point. I'll change that. Regardless of the threshold, there is no "failure" (`Success = False`) in the logs during that time period.